# Non AMD libraries using Requirejs

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs, amd

I am working on existing application where we have couple of modules(Non AMD) from some third party. 
They use name space so for example we have below libraries.

- DM
- DM.Voice
- DM.Audio

Now I am trying to intergrate require js in my project. How do I configure these dependencies. I was looking at shim. But did not really understand it. Can any one give a bit clear explanation about that. Also is it same for using jquery and jquery plugin like scroll?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

assuming your public html directory looks like this:

```
html
 - index.html
 js
  - jquery.js
  - main.js
  - jquery.scroll.js
  - dm.js
  - require.js
```

Then in index.html you want:

```
<script data-main="js/main" src="js/require.js"></script>
```

in main.js:

```
require.config({
     shim: {
        'dm': {
            exports: 'DM'
       },

      "jquery.scroll": ["jquery"]
     }
});

require( [ 'jquery', 'jquery.scroll'], function( $ ) {
 // use $ here
});
```